# Failed to cargo release build `libc v0.2.142` on Mac M1

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo

I have a rust project which is failing to do a release build because it can't build `libc v0.2.142`. Weirdly `cargo build` works.

```
   Compiling libc v0.2.142
     Running `/Users/twitu/Code/nautilus_trader/nautilus_core/target/release/build/libc-47ec154ab84f196d/build-script-build`
error: failed to run custom build command for `libc v0.2.142`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/twitu/Code/nautilus_trader/nautilus_core/target/release/build/libc-47ec154ab84f196d/build-script-build` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
```

```
active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Users/twitu/Code/nautilus_trader/nautilus_core/rust-toolchain.toml')
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
```

Is it by any chance related to clang version which I updated recently. It also failed for `16.0.2` and `14.0.6` for me.

```
Homebrew clang version 15.0.7
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

A colleague with clang `14.0.3` can successfully build it. Otherwise I'm clueless how such a low level library is failing, and specifically for release builds.

Comment: Signal 9 looks like it was killed by something.

Comment: Have you tried using clang 14.0.3 in your system?

Comment: I actually upgraded to `16.0.2` and still didn't work. Will try `14.0.3` as well.

Comment: Nope doesn't build for `14.0.6` either